# Include another field in the select statement which must not be part of the distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I include another column in the select statement without making it part of the distinct? I tried to set another column name before the distinct but that did not work.

```
SELECT  distinct nm.LeadConsumerId, nm.LeadMetaInfoId         

  FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LeadConsumer] as lc
  inner join [dbo].[LeadNMConsumer] as nm on lc.ID = nm.LeadConsumerId
  inner join [dbo].BrokerHistories as his on nm.LeadConsumerId = his.LeadConsumerId
  where (his.EventType = 0 Or his.EventType = 1) 
  AND his.EventDate >= Convert(datetime, '2016-05-01') AND his.EventDate <= Convert(datetime, '2016-05-31')
```

Comment: How do you determine which row, among the duplicates, would be included?

Comment: Switch from SELECT DISTINCT to a SELECT with GROUP BY. Use max/min to chose that new column.

Comment: I did the group by, now I have the same situation: distinct 2 columns,  but I cant include other columns...

Comment: @Elisabeth - that's because you've still not articulated (to us, and to the server), *which* values should be selected for those columns. You have *multiple* rows which are distinct for 2 columns but contain *multiple* different values in these other columns. What *rules* do you want us (and the server) to apply to choose those values? For instance, Felix's current answer is "arbitrarily select values for the other columns, but all column values will come from a single source row" - but is that the *correct* definition you want to apply?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  
        nm.LeadConsumerId,
        nm.LeadMetaInfoId,
        -- other columns you want
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY nm.LeadConsumerId,   nm.LeadMetaInfoId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LeadConsumer] AS lc
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LeadNMConsumer] AS nm
        ON lc.ID = nm.LeadConsumerId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].BrokerHistories AS his
        ON nm.LeadConsumerId = his.LeadConsumerId
    WHERE
        (his.EventType = 0 OR his.EventType = 1)
        AND his.EventDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '2016-05-01')
        AND his.EventDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '2016-05-31')
)
SELECT
    --list all columns you want 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Replace `(SELECT NULL)` from the `ORDER BY` clause as preferred.

Comment: your query does not execute. There is something wrong with the ")" => Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Sorry for returning that late...I got another task and have to return to this one...I tried to add the columns  nm.LeadConsumerId,
        nm.LeadMetaInfoId from the CTE into the Select at the bottom, but its always complaining about the third column which is the Row_Number, how do I handle that?

Comment: ok I put the 'AS rn" after the Row_Number at then it worked, but the data returned is WRONG. I get data from older month which can not be true.